# Not another SQL time between dates minus weekends question

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two dates: `CREATION_DATE` and `START_DATE`. `START_DATE` will always be later than `CREATION_DATE`. I need to calculate the number of minutes between them, except for minutes which happen on a weekend.

Every solution I can find assumes one of those dates *occurs* on a weekend, but alas, if `CREATION_DATE` is on a Friday, and `START_DATE` is a Monday, all of Saturday and Sunday is counted.

I've even tried calculating minutes from `CREATION_DATE` to the next 12am occurs *plus* minutes from first 12am Monday to `START_DATE`, but that doesn't work either.

I have found a solution if I only wanted to count days. I need to know down to minutes.

Our DB is hosted an I am not able to create VB functions so my solution must be all SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I calculate there's how many weekend days between two dates in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221690/can-i-calculate-theres-how-many-weekend-days-between-two-dates-in-sql-server)

Comment: The above answer may not work *across years*.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to generate a record for **all** minutes between the start and finish, including those on weekends. Then use the `WHERE` clause to filter out those you don't want. In many cases, this is done by joining to a `Calendar` table, so you can also look at holidays or other special events, but for this purpose we can just use the `DATEPART()` function.

One this is done, we use a `GROUP BY` to roll things back up to the original date values and the `COUNT()` function to know how much work we did.

This basic concept works whether you're counting days, minutes, months, whatever.

It's not clear in the question, but I'm gonna assume your start and end values are columns in a table, rather than variable names (no `@`).

```
WITH Numbers(Number) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]) - 1
    FROM sys.all_columns AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns AS s2
)
SELECT t.CREATION_DATE, t.START_DATE, COUNT(*) AS Num_Minutes
FROM [MyTable] t
INNER JOIN Numbers n on n.Number <= DATEDIFF(minute, t.CREATION_DATE, t.START_DATE)
WHERE DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(minute, n.Number, t.CREATION_DATE)) NOT IN (7,1)
GROUP BY t.CREATION_DATE, t.START_DATE
```

But this has the potential to be very slow, depending on how far apart the dates are. You can improve this by using various other ways to generate the `Numbers` table to get a starting point that better approximates the needs of your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't worried about accounting for holidays, you can do this as a simple math problem without having to monkey around with a tally table or doing any counting.
The following works by dropping the time portion off the begin and end date parameters and calculates the number of working days from that and multiples that figure by 3660. From there, if the begin date is a week day the begin date mins are subtracted... if end date is a weekday, those mins are added.

```
DECLARE
    @BegDate DATETIME = '2018-09-13 03:30:30',
    @EndDate DATETIME = '2018-09-18 03:35:27';

SELECT 
    working_mins = bm.base_mins
                    - ((1 - (x.is_beg_sat + x.is_beg_sun)) * x.beg_mins)    -- if the begin date is a week day, subtract the mins from midnight.
                    + ((1 - (x.is_end_sat + x.is_end_sun)) * x.end_mins)    -- if the end date is a week day add the mins from midnight.
    --,*
FROM
    ( VALUES (
            DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @BegDate), 0), 
            DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @EndDate), 0)
            ) ) d (beg_date, end_date)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, d.beg_date, @BegDate),
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, d.end_date, @EndDate),
            DATEDIFF(DAY, d.beg_date, d.end_date),
            DATEDIFF(WEEK, d.beg_date, d.end_date) * 2,
            1 - SIGN(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d.beg_date) % 7),
            1 - SIGN(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d.end_date) % 7),
            1 - SIGN((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d.beg_date) + 7) % 8),
            1 - SIGN((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d.end_date) + 7) % 8)
            ) ) x (beg_mins, end_mins, total_days, weekend_days, is_beg_sat, is_end_sat, is_beg_sun, is_end_sun)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (1440 * (x.total_days - x.weekend_days + x.is_beg_sat - x.is_end_sat)) ) bm (base_mins);
```

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining it well as this does end up with the result I am looking for. Basically, I want the end result of difference between:  '2018-09-21 23:59:00',
     and  '2018-09-24 00:01:00' to be 2 minutes.

Comment: @Mattrajotte, you explination is fine. For whatever reason I used 3660 instead of 1440 as the number minutes in a day (I'm not sure how the heck I managed that mistake). In any case the code has been updated and the the new result for your test values is 2 mins.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this solution, and see if meets your needs. Basically, I did the following:

1. Take the number of whole days betwen `StartDate` and `EndDate` that aren't weekend days, and multiply by 2:

   `SELECT COUNT(*) * 24 * 60 FROM WholeDaysBetween WHERE wkday <= 5`
2. Take the minutes from `StartDate` (`hours*60 + minutes`)

   `(24 * 60) - (DATEPART(HOUR, @StartDate) * 60) - (DATEPART(MINUTE, @StartDate))`
3. Take the minutes from `EndDate` (`hours*60 + minutes`)

   `(DATEPART(HOUR, @EndDate) * 60) + (DATEPART(MINUTE, @EndDate))`

To get the number of whole days between, I used a recursive CTE:

```
WITH
    WholeDaysBetween(dt, wkday) AS
    (
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate), DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate))
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, dt), DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, 1, dt))
        FROM WholeDaysBetween
        WHERE dt < DATEADD(DAY, -1, @EndDate)
    )
```

Of course, for this to work, you have to [adjust your datefirst settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

The final query is as follows (I used the same sample data as in your comment):

```
set datefirst 1; -- day starts on Monday

declare @StartDate datetime = '2018-09-21 23:59:00';
declare @EndDate datetime = '2018-09-24 00:01:00';

WITH
    WholeDaysBetween(dt, wkday) AS
    (
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate), DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate))
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, dt), DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, 1, dt))
        FROM WholeDaysBetween
        WHERE dt < DATEADD(DAY, -1, @EndDate)
    )

SELECT
    -- whole weekdays between @StartDate and @EndDate, 
    -- multiplied by minutes per day
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) * 24 * 60
        FROM WholeDaysBetween
        WHERE wkday <= 5
    ) 
    +
    -- minutes from @StartDate date to end of @StartDate
    -- as long as @StartDate isn't on weekend
    (
        SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) <= 5
                THEN
                (24 * 60) - 
                (DATEPART(HOUR, @StartDate) * 60) - 
                (DATEPART(MINUTE, @StartDate))
                ELSE 0
            END
    )
    +
    -- minutes from start of @EndDate's date to @EndDate
    -- as long as @EndDate isn't on weekend
    (
        SELECT 
            CASE
            WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @EndDate) <= 5
            THEN
                (DATEPART(HOUR, @EndDate) * 60) +
                (DATEPART(MINUTE, @EndDate))
            ELSE 0
            END
    )
```